# Nuxt not being reactive and some errors in console

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working in a Nuxt project for managing some personal data

Somehow, the project is not being reactive and it means each change I make I have to refresh it or even stop + run again in console

[image: Console Description]

This is the index.vue file. As you can see there's nothing much that could trigger this behavior

```
<template>
  <div class="index-container">
    <!-- <Datasheet></Datasheet> -->
    <!-- <LandingSelector class="min-h-screen"/> -->
   <!--  <FireSparks class="fire-sparks" /> -->
   Hello World
  </div>
</template>

<script>



export default {
    name: "IndexPage",
    
}
</script>

<style>
.fire-sparks {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100; /* Ensure the sparks appear on top of other elements */
}


/* div{
  border: solid 1px red;
} */
</style>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.